# Django - Admin - Add link in a change_form that redirect to another change_form - set field with a value

Tags: python, django, admin

I have open a post dealing with this subject but had no answer...

to resume:
I have a form #1 with a link
when I click on this link, a new form #2 with a sub-form open

now, I would like a field of the form #2 (open after clicking on the link of form #1) to be pre-filled with a value that come from the form #1

all this take place in the admin part of Django

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Participante, Visite, Inclusion, BilanBiologique, ExamenBiologique

class ExamenBiologiqueInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ExamenBiologique
    extra = 0

class BilanBiologiqueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ExamenBiologiqueInline,]

class BilanBiologiqueLinkInline(admin.TabularInline):
    readonly_fields = ('examen', )
    model = BilanBiologique
    extra = 0
    fields = ('bio_ide', 'vis', 'bio_dat',)

class VisiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BilanBiologiqueLinkInline,]

class InclusionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('examen',)
    model = Inclusion
    fields = ('vis',('inc_tdr','examen'),)


admin.site.register(Participante)
admin.site.register(Visite, VisiteAdmin)
admin.site.register(BilanBiologique, BilanBiologiqueAdmin)
admin.site.register(Inclusion, InclusionAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class Participante(models.Model):

    pat_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pat_ide_prn_cse = models.CharField("Identifiant Princesse",
        max_length=14,
        validators = [
            RegexValidator(
                regex='^SP[M|F][0-9]{11}$',
                message= 'L\'identifiant doit être au format requis',
                code='invalid_participant_id'
            ),
        ], 
        unique=True
        )
    pat_inc_dat = models.DateField("Date d'inclusion")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pat_ide_prn_cse}"

class Visite(models.Model):
    vis_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pat = models.ForeignKey(Participante, verbose_name='Participante', related_name='visites', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vis_dat = models.DateField("Date de consultation")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pat.pat_ide_prn_cse} / {self.vis_dat}"

class BilanBiologique(models.Model):
    bio_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vis = models.ForeignKey(Visite, verbose_name='Visite', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio_dat = models.DateField("Date de prélèvement")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bio_ide}"

    @property
    def date_visite(self):
        return self.vis.vis_dat

    date_visite.fget.short_description = 'Date de la visite'

    @property
    def participante(self):
        return self.vis.pat.pat_ide_prn_cse

    participante.fget.short_description = 'Participante'

class ExamenBiologique(models.Model):
    bio_exa_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bio = models.ForeignKey(BilanBiologique, verbose_name='Bilans', related_name='examens',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio_exa_cod = models.IntegerField("Type d'examen")
    bio_exa_res_num = models.FloatField("Résultat numérique", null=True, blank=True)
    bio_exa_res_mod = models.IntegerField("Résultat modalité", null=True, blank=True)
    bio_exa_uni = models.IntegerField("Unité", null=True, blank=True)
    bio_exa_val_inf = models.FloatField("Limite inférieure", null=True, blank=True)
    bio_exa_val_sup = models.FloatField("Limite supérieure", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bio_exa_ide}"

class Inclusion(models.Model):
    readonly_fields = ('examen',)

    inc_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    vis = models.ForeignKey(Visite, verbose_name='Visite', related_name='inclusions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inc_tdr = models.IntegerField("Test rapide Determine® VHB (AgHBs)")

    def examen(self):
        changeform_url = reverse('admin:ecrf_bilanbiologique_add')
        return mark_safe('<a href="{u}" target="_blank">Ajouter un bilan</a>'.format(u=changeform_url))
    examen.short_description =''
    examen.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):

        return f"{self.vis} / {self.inc_ide}"
```

Comment: You're showing us some code but I don't see form#1, form#2 (you haven't defined any forms in your admin.py code) nor which field should be prefilled with which data. Please be specific and refer to the names of variables, fields and classes in your code: what is form#1, form#2, the link you click, the field to fill in, the field to fetch the data from?

Comment: I use the default admin form ; I mean I did not override any admin template

Comment: But you still need to explain what is form#1, form#2 etc. We can’t guess. E.g. form1 is the admin change form for the model ExamenBiologique, displayed by the model admin ExamenBiologiqueAdmin. etc...

Comment: sorry... form #1 is InclusionAdmin based on Inclusion and form #2 is BilanBiologiqueLinkInline based on BilanBiologique (main form) and ExamenBiologique (sub-form)

Comment: any idea for help me?